# NodeJS jwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt from requests error in MERN

Tags: mern

```
C:\Users\Nalin\Desktop\devconnector\config\passport.js:2
jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
^

ReferenceError: jwtOptions is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nalin\Desktop\devconnector\config\passport.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nalin\Desktop\devconnector\server.js:29:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context?

Comment: i fixed i missed   secretOrKey: "secret", anyway thanks so much.